# When to call my completion block if I have multiple asynchronous calls

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

I'm a bit confused on how to use closures or in my case a completion block effectively. In my case, I want to call a block of code when some set of asynchronous calls have completed, to let my caller know if there was an error or success, etc.

So an example of what I'm trying to accomplish might look like the following:

```
// Caller
updatePost(forUser: user) { (error, user) in 
   if let error = error {
      print(error.description) 
   }

   if let user = user {
      print("User was successfully updated")
      // Do something with the user...
   }
}   


public func updatePost(forUser user: User, completion: @escaping (Error?, User?) -> () {

     // Not sure at what point, and where to call completion(error, user)
     // so that my caller knows the user has finished updating

     // Maybe this updates the user in the database
     someAsyncCallA { (error)

     }

     // Maybe this deletes some old records in the database
     someAsyncCallB { (error)

     }

}
```

So ideally, I want my completion block to be called when async block B finishes (assuming async block A finished already, I know this is a BAD assumption). But what happens in the case that async block B finishes first and async block A takes a lot longer? If I call my completion after async block B, then my caller thinks that the method has finished.

In a case like this, say I want to tell the user when updating has finished, but I only really know it has finished when both async blocks have finished. How do I tackle this or am I just using closures wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your question has been answered. What I think you are looking for is a DispatchGroup.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
someAsyncCallA(completion: {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
})
dispatchGroup.enter()
someAsyncCallB(completion: {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
})
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    // When you get here, both calls are done and you can do what you want. 
})
```

Really important note: `enter()` and `leave()` calls **must balance**, otherwise you crash with an exception.

Comment: look into semaphores as well if you are using a shared resource

Answer (score -1):

try below code:

```
public func updatePost(forUser user: User, completion: @escaping (Error?, User?) -> () {

     // Not sure at what point, and where to call completion(error, user)
     // so that my caller knows the user has finished updating

     // Maybe this updates the user in the database
     someAsyncCallA { (error)
         // Maybe this deletes some old records in the database
         someAsyncCallB { (error)
             completion()
         }
     }
}
```

please try updated answer below:

```
public func updatePost(forUser user: User, completion: @escaping (Error?, User?) -> () {
    var isTaskAFinished = false
    var isTaskBFinished = false
         // Not sure at what point, and where to call completion(error, user)
         // so that my caller knows the user has finished updating

    // Maybe this updates the user in the database
    someAsyncCallA { (error)
          // Maybe this deletes some old records in the database
          isTaskAFinished = true
          if isTaskBFinished{
              completion()
          }
    }

    someAsyncCallB { (error)
         isTaskBFinished = true
         if isTaskAFinished{
               completion()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I've been doing, but in some cases I want to do both calls separately so that say my update call doesn't take that much time.